# Scala alternative constructor vs. companion object for polymorphic constructors

Tags: scala, constructor

What is considered the correct way to create polymorphic constructors in Scala? On the one hand, I can use a companion object:

```
class UserRecord (override val userID: String,
                       override val rep: Int) extends Record

object UserRecord extends Record {
  def apply(line: String) = {
    val elem = XML.loadString(line)

    val userID = elem \ "@Id" text
    val rep = (elem \ "@Reputation" text).toInt
    val out = new UserRecord(userID, rep)
    out
  }
}
```

but this loses some encapsulation, and the call to the object without `new` obscures the fact that a non-singleton object is being created. On the other hand, I can use a sequence of alternate constructors, which is a bit clunky:

```
class UserRecord (override val userID: String,
                       override val rep: Int) extends Record {
  def this(t: Tuple2[String, Int]) = this(t._1, t._2)

  def this(line: String) = this({
    val elem = XML.loadString(line)

    val userID = elem \ "@Id" text
    val rep = (elem \ "@Reputation" text).toInt
    val out = (userID, rep)
    out
  })
}
```

I've also looked for ways to avoid using the first alternate constructor using `.tupled` but haven't really cracked that nut.

Comment: What do you mean by clunky? If you have three constructors, you have to have three "def this" methods. Companion object looks less clunky only because there you have only (line: String) case.

Comment: I mean that I haven't figured out how to avoid the construction of the first constructor that takes Tuple2 as parameter.

Comment: Scala definitely favors the `apply` method for this. The standard library is littered with this sort of thing.

Comment: +1 for companion objects. When the number of `apply` methods get out of hand, you might want to consider the magnet pattern (http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).